# Nest js + prisma project, error in findUnique method in services

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I have question what I am doing wrong, when use prisma with nest.
I am getting this error

```
src/modules/auth/auth.service.ts:28:63 - error TS2322: Type 'UserWhereUniqueInput' is not assignable to type 'string'.
28     const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });
                                                                 ~~~~~

  node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:1521:5
    1521     email?: string
             ~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'email' which is declared here on type 'UserWhereUniqueInput'
[11:50:56 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes
```

[prisma error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfv98.png)

in auth.service.ts

```
...
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService, private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async signIn({
    email,
    password,
  }: {
    email: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput;
    password: string;
  }) {
    const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });
...
```

my schema of user is next

```
model User {
 id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
 email      String   @unique
 password   String
 lastName   String?
 firstName  String?
 roles      String[]
}
```

controller which is calling service is

```
...
@Post('sign-in')
  signIn(@Body() signinAuthDto: any) {
    return this.authService.signIn(signinAuthDto);
  }
```

I have added here any instead of
SigninAuthDto but it still fails

```
export class SigninAuthDto {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make the type for property email in method signIn just string? The issue is you are trying to type email which is a string, to an object, prisma unique input.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService, private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async signIn({
    email,
    password,
  }: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  }) {
    const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: if I am adding types to service arguments it is crashing with errors.  <html>TS2345: Argument of type '{ email: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ select?: UserSelect; rejectOnNotFound?: RejectOnNotFound; where: UserWhereUniqueInput; }'.<br/>Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'email' does not exist in type '{ select?: UserSelect; rejectOnNotFound?: RejectOnNotFound; where: UserWhereUniqueInput; }'.

Comment: only if i remove typing in arguments it works

Comment: create of user  without types the error is next ``` Argument of type '{ email: any; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ select?: UserSelect; data: (Without&lt;UserCreateInput, UserUncheckedCreateInput&gt; &amp; UserUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without&lt;...&gt; &amp; UserCreateInput); }'.<br/>Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'email' does not exist in type '{ select?: UserSelect; data: (Without&lt;UserCreateInput, UserUncheckedCreateInput&gt; &amp; UserUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without&lt;...&gt; &amp; UserCreateInput); }'.```

Comment: @VictorOrlyk You described two different errors. I tried locally and typing `email` as `string` works with `findUnique` without error. Can you please update your question to include how you are trying to create the user?

Answer (score 0):

I've been in a similar situation as well. The answer to this would be making user a unique field.
You can easily do this by adding @unique in front of email in your schema.prisma file

```
model User {
 id       String @id @default(cuid())
 name     String
 email    String @unique
 username String
 password String
}
```

This tells prisma to add email to the UserWhereUniqueInput type which is mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In my case **reopened vscode** problem was gone.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35374877)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).